# Getting search result from instance in calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need to get the event that has the given string . For example : i need to get the all events that contains the word "test" for three days. If i run the below it showing all the events for the three days.

```
long begin = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long end =  begin + (86000000*3);
System.out.println("01 - begin: " +begin+" end "+end);
String[] proj = new String[]{Instances._ID, 
                Instances.TITLE,
                Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
                Instances.BEGIN, 
                Instances.END, 
                Instances.END, 
                Instances.EVENT_ID};
Cursor cursor =  Instances.query(context.getContentResolver(), proj, begin, end);
```

When i tried the below query it giving the res

```
Cursor cursor = Instances.query(context.getContentResolver(), proj, begin, end,"test");
```

I dont know where i made the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear, can you rephrase it?

Comment: search functionality of calendar.